# Properly migrating Postgres database to Docker/Django/Heroku/Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I have a Django project hosted on an IIS server with a Postgresql database that I am migrating to Docker/Heroku project. I have found a few good resources online, but no luck yet completely. I have tried to use the dumpdata/loaddata function but always run into constraint errors, missing relations, or content type errors. I would like to just dump the whole database and then restore the whole thing to Docker. Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
    networks:
      - hello-world
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - '.:/code'
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - hello-world
networks:
  hello-world:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to resolve this I believe with the following command: "docker exec -i postgres pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d  < ./latest.dump"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).